# Space between two buttons in Material Design

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two buttons and would like to put a space between them. So, I have tried to do that by putting a box around them and then applying a margin to the box. See code below.

```
    render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Header />
          </BrowserRouter>
        </ThemeProvider>

        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Grid container justify="center">
            <Box pt={3}>
              <Paper>
                <Box pl={3} pr={3} pb={3} pt={3}>
                  <Grid container spacing={0}>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                      <Typography
                        variant="h6"
                        gutterBottom={false}
                        onClick={this.handleSetDummyText}
                      >
                        Keyword Processor
                      </Typography>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                      {/* ********* Offending code section ********** */}
                      <Button
                        color={
                          this.state.sorttypeStatus === 'default'
                            ? 'primary'
                            : 'secondary'
                        }
                        onClick={this.handleSortDefault}
                      >
                        DEFAULT
                      </Button>
                      {/* ********* Offending code section ********** */}
                      <Button
                        color={
                          this.state.sorttypeStatus === 'alpha'
                            ? 'primary'
                            : 'secondary'
                        }
                        onClick={this.handleSortAlpha}
                      >
                        A-Z
                      </Button>
                      <Button
                        color={
                          this.state.sorttypeStatus === 'length'
                            ? 'primary'
                            : 'secondary'
                        }
                        onClick={this.handleSortLength}
                      >
                        LENGTH
                      </Button>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid container spacing={2}>
                      <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <TextField
                          label="Input Keywords"
                          fullWidth
                          multiline
                          rows={10}
                          variant="outlined"
                          margin="normal"
                          onChange={this.handleInputText}
                          // defaultValue={defaultInputText}
                          value={this.state.inputText}
                        />

                        <Box m={1}>
                          <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={this.inputToOutput}
                          >
                            Parse
                          </Button>

                          <Button
                            variant="outlined"
                            color="secondary"
                            onClick={this.clearInput}
                            // default={this.state.inputText}
                          >
                            Clear
                          </Button>
                        </Box>

                        <br />
                        <Checkboxes
                          handleDedupe={this.handleDedupe}
                          handleRemoveNumbers={this.handleRemoveNumbers}
                          handleConvertToLowercase={
                            this.handleConvertToLowercase
                          }
                          handleOneWordPerLine={this.handleOneWordPerLine}
                          handleAddCommas={this.handleAddCommas}
                          handleAddCommasSpace={this.handleAddCommasSpace}
                          handleStartWords={this.handleStartWords}
                          handleEndWords={this.handleEndWords}
                        />
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <TextField
                          label="Output Keywords"
                          fullWidth
                          multiline
                          rows={30}
                          variant="outlined"
                          margin="normal"
                          value={this.state.outputText}
                        />
                        <Button
                          variant="contained"
                          color="primary"
                          mt={5}
                          onClick={() => {
                            navigator.clipboard.writeText(
                              this.state.outputText
                            );
                          }}
                        >
                          Copy
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          variant="outlined"
                          color="secondary"
                          mt={5}
                          onClick={this.clearOutput}
                        >
                          Clear
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                          variant="outlined"
                          color="secondary"
                          mt={5}
                          onClick={this.handleSetDummyText}
                        >
                          Dummy Data
                        </Button>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Box>
              </Paper>
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

But the boxes seem to stick together like glue! I do have a custom theme but I cannot seem to get that to work with my App.js file because I am using a class component, rather than a functional component. I understand that you are supposed to use withStyles with class components, but I have struggled to get that to work. So, as a fix, I am trying the Box method.

Any idea how to get my box method to work?

Answer (score 2):

you could use Grid component of material ui and as justify content use `space-between`

```
<Grid
  style={{width:'140px'}}
  container
  direction="row"
  justify="space-between"
  alignItems="center">
   <Button/>// here are the buttons 
   <Button/>
   </Grid>
```

read more about the `Grid` https://material-ui.com/components/grid/

or you could do it with `<div/>` i used inline style so that you can read it
easier

```
<div style ={{ width:'200px',
display:'flex',
flexDirection:'row',
justifyContent:'space-between'
}}>
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
</div>
```

see working examples with div https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-taussig-jyesc?file=/src/App.js:67-263

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put each button in a box?

```
<div>
  <Box m={1}>
    <Button variant="contained">one</Button>
  </Box>
  <Box m={1}>
    <Button variant="contained">two</Button>
  </Box>
</div>
```

Comment: When I use a Box around each button, the second button goes to a new line.

Comment: @Jon in that case just add display: flex to the wrapper div or you can add component="span" to the box

Answer (score 1):

The `<Box>` component works like a `<div>`, it is a block, so your code can not align buttons in a row.

You can use `flex-box` to style to get what you want. Use `Grid` `item`, `container` and `spacing` API of `Grid` fit your need as well.

Below is an example:

```
<Grid container spacing={4}>
  <Grid item xs={2}>
    <Button fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">
      button A{" "}
    </Button>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={2}>
    <Button fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">
      button B{" "}
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

- When using `<Grid container>`, you create a flex-box container. By default on ReactJS, the flex-items inside will be aligned by row. That's the reason why We do not have to declare props `direction="row"` on the container.
- You can change the `spacing` value to change the space between two Grid items. By default, `1 = 8px` and it can be customized in material ui as well.
- `xs` indicates the size of your screen, in material ui we have 5 of them `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg` and `xl`, you can read about it in material ui docs.
- `fullWidth` buttons just to make the buttons take the whole width of containers for ease of seeing space between buttons.

Working example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wescoff-lnj71?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried that code but it did not do anything.

Comment: Edited, Take a look on that.

Comment: "it is a block, so your code can not align buttons in a row."
My buttons are aligned in a row, but there is no space between them, unless I have misunderstood what you meant by align buttons in a row. My Grid container already has spacing set. I just tried on the Grid that contains the two input buttons and spacing didn't make any visible changes.

Comment: Just additional explanation becasue I do not see the Grid in your code.

Comment: Please update your code and I will update my answer. I think the problem is just placed Grid item and container incorrectly.

Comment: I've updated my code now. I hope that helps. I've got lots of nested stuff going on and it has gotten confusing.

Comment: I found a solution using withStyles. See it here: [link][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920277/styling-class-components-with-an-alternative-to-makestyles]