# Styling Class Components with an alternative to makeStyles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am seeing examples of using the makeStyles hook so you can style your functional component in Material Design. But I am using a class component and so can't use hooks. The code I see being used for functional components is as follows:

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    }));
```

And then for styling the elements in the return() section, they do something like this:

`className={classes.margin}`

How do I do the same type of thing but for a class component?

Comment: You can just use `CSS` in external stylesheet and import it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for class component you can use `withStyles` wrapper.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return <div className={classes.styledLine}>Styling using withStyles</div>;
    }
}

const useStyles = (theme) => ({
    styledLine: {
        color: "red"
    }
});

export default withStyles(useStyles)(App);
```

Working demo:-
[image: Edit smoosh-morning-tjh7y]

Comment: I am struggling to get that to work. The error message says "Unexpected token" and it points to "const" just after render. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I'm not sure. the demo I've provided is working fine. have you followed the same pattern in your code as I've done in the demo?

Comment: Don't use the `makeStyles`

Comment: My apologies. I put the const after return, not before. Doh! A big thanks for this. All working now. I've spent days trying to work out how to do this!!